# android "layout_alignParentBottom" in relative layout

Tags: android, alignment, android-relativelayout

So, I have this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/layout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#FFFF00"
                android:minHeight="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        >
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:background="#FF0000"
            android:text="Hello World"
            />

    <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="button"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is how it looks:

[image]

but if I add `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to the button here is how it looks:

[image]

1. Can someone please explain me this behavior?
2. How to put my button at the bottom without resizing the yellow layout and without adding thousand of layouts for workarounds?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this solution worked for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/layout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#FFFF00"
                android:minHeight="100dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        >
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:background="#FF0000"
            android:text="Hello World"
            />

    <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:text="button"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

this one fast one screen

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#FFFF00"
    android:minHeight="100dp" >



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: this is not working because it doesn't keep into account minHeight from main relative layout

Answer (score 1):

just for try, can you double the min size of your layout and try it again?
or maybe you can set a fix the hight of the layout and change it dynamically from the code when needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#FFFF00"
    android:minHeight="100dp" >

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:background="#FF0000"
            android:text="Hello World"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

try this code

Comment: using your code it makes my layout to cover all the screen because you've used  android:layout_height="fill_parent" and I want that my layout to keep it's height as seen in my first screenshot

Comment: so I want my layout look like my first image, except that my button should be aligned to bottom.

Comment: this one you give size moer button to change

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately bug still exists in newer versions of android.

Anyway, I found that following can solve that problem :

1. Delete minHeight of RelativeLayout
2. Insert TextView in a LinearLayout:

   ```
   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/tvLayout"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:minHeight="100dp"
       android:gravity="top"
       >
       <TextView 
           android:id="@+id/tv"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:background="#FFFF00FF"
           android:text="Helo"
           />
   </LinearLayout>
   ```
3. Delete layout_alignParentBottom from Button and add layout_alignBottom="@id/tvLayout"

Now LinearLayout "controls" the height of RelativeLayout.
If TextView height is bigger than minHeight of 100dp, it will expand.

And button will always align its bottom to LinearLayout, equal to RelativeLayout one.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a responsive UI with ConstraintLayout

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

The result layout will looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#FFFF00"
    android:minHeight="100dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The preview is:
[image]

Read more here - 
https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/08/understanding-performance-benefits-of.html